# Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir '/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-756035' when install puppeteer on vps

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I try to deploy my nodejs app on vps ubuntu but getting error when npm install puppeteer.

[image]

If I run 'PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD=true npm i puppeteer', it installed but my code getting error not found chrome.
Thank for help

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be caused by the lack of libs used by puppeteer [listed here for Ubuntu](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-headless-doesnt-launch-on-unix).

`sudo apt-get install` the following before npm install:

```
ca-certificates
fonts-liberation
gconf-service
libappindicator1
libasound2
libatk-bridge2.0-0
libatk1.0-0
libc6
libcairo2
libcups2
libdbus-1-3
libexpat1
libfontconfig1
libgbm1
libgcc1
libgconf-2-4
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
libglib2.0-0
libgtk-3-0
libnspr4
libnss3
libpango-1.0-0
libpangocairo-1.0-0
libstdc++6
libx11-6
libx11-xcb1
libxcb1
libxcomposite1
libxcursor1
libxdamage1
libxext6
libxfixes3
libxi6
libxrandr2
libxrender1
libxss1
libxtst6
lsb-release
wget
xdg-utils
```

You should also launch puppeteer with `--no-sandbox`:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox'] })
```

From your question it is not clear which VPS do you use, but many providers has their own buildpack for puppeteer (e.g.: [Heroku](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack)), you may need to look for that if the above solution doesn't work.